# How to display plain text content referencing an id in the same html-file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a hard time coming up with a descriptive title, but this is the best I could do. Anyways, I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) about creating a hoverable menu and it works like a charm, but now comes the problem when I want to reference the id

```
<a href="#element1">Link 1</a>
```

I have set for the dropdown-content. I would want to do something like this in the *same* html-file:

```
<div id="element1">
    <article>
    <h1>This is the page to element 1</h1>
    <p> Some plain text... </p>
    </article>
</div>
```

But this content only shows up on the index page and not on the page which I want to be dedicated to "element1". Now, you could probably make another html-file and reference to it, but as I was working with *JQuery* the other day, the above code worked the way I intended.

Is there any way to do this without another html-file or do you simply have to start writing some Javascript to make everything work?

Comment: You should not set multiple elements with the same id.
Each id on a page needs to be unique.

Try changing the id from `element1`, on the new element, to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to read up on JQuery and try out the show/hide options, and it worked. I also needed to hide the content of an id with the *style* tag from the beginning.